# Extracting Date from exported data

Tags: string, excel, date, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a field in an imported set of data I which I need to use in the creation of a tables which needs to selectively display information for certain date periods so having the date in a recognisable field is essential.

The field appears as: `Wed Jan 21 00:00:22 CST 2015`

I have tried variations of the below but can't seem to get it to pull out the date properly:

```
=DATEVALUE((LEFT(RIGHT(A1;18);4))&"2015")

=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(A1;18);4))
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: If it is in date format try =Format(a1,"mm/dd/yyyy"). This will give you a predictable format of 01/21/2015 for the date above. If what you have posted is stored as a text field, it will be a bit more tricky.

Comment: @Kyle it is a text field although I can change that when I import the CSV - should I make it a general field on import instead? Or a date field perhaps?

Comment: I would recommend a date field. That tends to make it easy to use =Format() to get it to display as you would like. The responses below look as though they would work as well.

Comment: Thanks. Pnuts found something which works perfectly. Appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MATCH(MID(A1,5,3),{"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"},0),MID(A1,9,2))
```

Comment: You are a legend! This work 100%

Thank you very much for helping me find a solution :)

Comment: Well spotted! That could have been a problem in next months report once that changes to feb.
Thanks a lot!